# Performance of set in Java vs List in java

Tags: java, collections, java-8

consider the following code

```
List<Integer> l=new ArrayList();
Set<Integer> l=new HashSet();
```

which of the below for loop will be optimal

```
for(Integer i: some arrray){
    if(!l.contains(i))
    l.add(i);
}
```

or

```
 for(Integer i :some array){
   s.add(i);
}
```

Comment: Don't worry about performance. Use the right thing that your business need.

Comment: Think about what happens with your call to `contains` - every `Integer` that you add is eventually compared to every other `Integer` in the collection.  Those are exactly the kinds of comparison that a `HashSet` is designed to avoid.

Comment: `Collections.addAll(set, array)`

Comment: @Holger is this efficient that others

Comment: It’s at least as efficient as `for(Integer i: array) set.add(i);`. But for creating an entirely new set, you may do even better: `Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(array));`

Comment: Thanks got your point

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) offers a constant time performance for the `add` method (it uses a `HashMap` behind the scenes). Assuming the size of `some arrray` is `m` - the overall time complexity is `O(m)`.

If you use an `ArrayList`, the worst-case complexity of `contains` in `O(n)` (where `n` is the number of elements in the list `l`). So, the overall time complexity is `O(n * m)`

So a `Set` is better here (based on the code snippet posted) - But depends on what you are doing with it afterwards and whether a Set can support it.

Comment: The fact that `HashSet` uses `HashMap` behind the scenes is irrelevant. All that matters, is that [the specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) guarantees “*constant time performance for the basic operations (`add`, `remove`, `contains` and `size`)*” via whatever hash based implementation it will use internally.

Comment: @Holger True. It could have achieved the constant time performance by any other means... The spec also states *This class implements the Set interface, backed by a hash table (actually a HashMap instance)* as the first line :). Anyway, I have reworded my answer.

Comment: Yes, but that should not be treated as carved in stone. Actually, using a `HashMap` internally was a quick solution for the 1.2 release schedule and even the author said once “I can’t believe it’s still in use”, as it’s wasting a horrible amount of memory.

Comment: @Holger I see. Thanks for the points/comments. I haven't looked at the source code of Java 9, but I guess using the static method `Set.of` returns a private implementation of Set which is more efficient (than HashSet)

Comment: Yes, `Set.of` uses an entirely different implementation, as not only the efficiency, but also the fundamental behavior is different (immutable, not allowing `null`).